# Coffeescript rails select one of two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, coffeescript

I have two models in ruby,

```
@photos = Photo.all
@comments = Comment.all
@objects = @photos + @comments
```

I have in my html a button id"only-photo" and a button "only-comments", if i click on the first I want to select only the photos.
how can I do to only select @photos from @objects? in coffeescript

here is what i tried

```
<div id="list">
 <% @objects.each do |l| %>
   <% if l.class == "Photo"%>
     <div id="photo" class="photo">
      <%= render "shared/photo", :photo => l %>
     </div>
...
</div>

<div id="filters">
 <button id="only-photo">
 </button>
...
</div>
```

then in Coffeescript I just do:

```
$("#filters").on "click", "#only-photo", ->
 $("#list #comment").removeClass "active"
  $("#list #photo").addClass "active"
```

BUT I am sure there is a more elegant way to do these things!
Can't we filter on a scope from coffeescript? or anything like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you adding the two lists? Why not just maintain both and display them separately?

Comment: I don't think you should use HTML IDs but classes in this case.

Comment: @MrYoshjii yeah you are right, but still the same issue!
jordan, it is in a sort of "feed" for the user profile. But he can select the model he wants!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="list">
 <% @objects.each do |l| %>
   <div id="<%= l.class.to_s.downcase %>_<%= l.id %>" class="<%= l.class.to_s.downcase =%>">
    <%= render "shared/#{l.class.to_s.downcase}", :photo => l %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
</div>


<div id="filters">
  <button id="only-photo" class="filter" value="photo">
  </button>
  <button id="only-comment" class="filter" value="comment">
  </button>
  </button> 
</div>
```

Coffee:

```
$("button.filter").on "click", ->
  class_to_hide = $(this).attr('value')
  $("."+class_to_hide).toggleClass('active')
```

Comment: thank you for this response!
but here i get this: 
undefined method `downcase' for #<Class:0x007fe56fa254c0>

Comment: I just updated my answer (added `.to_s` before the `.downcase`) @PaulGhorra

Comment: thank you! sorry i can't vote up the answer, i don't have enough reputation...
Actually it is working, but you think that this way with toggleClasse is faster than hide and add class? Because mine was working too, is this one more efficient?

Comment: I don't know if it is more efficient but it is shorter and defined by the jQuery team. You can go check the source code to see what `toggleClass` really does. (I voted up for your question, I think now you have enough reputation to vote up)

Comment: Ok thank you! I still don't have enough sorry! I am new here! I have 8